# ListView.ItemCheck versus ListView.ItemChecked in .NET

Tags: .net, events, listview

What is the difference between the ListView.[ItemCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemcheck.aspx) and ListView.[ItemChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemchecked.aspx) events in .NET?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `ItemCheck` event is triggered when the checked state of an item *is about to change*, allowing you to examine the old and new value, and to cancel the change if you wish (by assigning the NewValue property of the eventargs parameter). `ItemChecked` is triggered *after the check (or uncheck) is completed*.

Code sample:

```
private void ListView_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    // the checked state of an item is about to change
    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        // perform some check if this is allowed, and if not...
        e.NewValue = e.CurrentValue;
    }
}

private void ListView_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
    // the checked state of an item has changed
}
```