# Checked List Box's Checked Items doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I have this Code for draw a diagram in a PictureBox:

```
    private void ChkLiboData_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
        try
        {
            foreach (DataClass d in ChkLiboData.CheckedItems)
            {
                if (d.r == null && d.g == null && d.b == null)
                {
                    Random r = new Random();

                    d.r = r.Next(0, 255);
                    d.g = r.Next(0, 255);
                    d.b = r.Next(0, 255);

                    DrawDiagram(d.DataList, (int)d.r, (int)d.g, (int)d.b);
                }
                else
                {
                    DrawDiagram(d.DataList, (int)d.r, (int)d.g, (int)d.b);
                }
                Refresh();
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

but in debug mod when I check an Item and I looked at `ChkLiboData.CheckedItems` I couldn't see any Items in `ChkLiboData.CheckedItems`.
what am I have to do???

Comment: possible duplicate of [No ItemChecked event in a CheckedListBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454058/no-itemchecked-event-in-a-checkedlistbox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event `ItemCheck` is raised when the checked status of an item is *about to be  changed*.  It isn't changed already. Let me show that with an example. The CheckedListBox contains 3 items "A", "B" and "C". No item is checked. Now the user checks the item "A". The event `ItemCheck` is fired. The property `CheckedItems` contains no item. In the event args `e` (of type `ItemCheckEventArgs`) you can find the index of the item which checked state is changing, a property `CurrentValue` containing the checked state before and a property `NewValue` containing the new checked state. If the user then checks item "B", the event is fired again. This time the property `CheckedItems` contains one item "A". a.s.o.

BTW: You can set the property `NewValue` in the ItemCheck event. This gives you the possibility e.g. to prevent an item to be checked.

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee: I've changed my answer according to your comment.