# Why ItemCheck Event Of CheckList Box Always One Behind?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a winform in which I have taken a checklist box. I want to store the checked items of checklist box in array list.There are 5 items in my checklist box and I want to handle `itemcheck` event.

if I check one item `itemcheck` event fires but items count remains 0 again if I check 2 items in event handler items count becomes 1 if I repeat this process next time count becomes 2(but now I have checked 3 items).

Please help me on this code below is the code snippet that I am using :

```
 private void CLB_Course_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {            
            List<string> items = new List<string>();            
            foreach (string ItemsChecked in CLB_Course.CheckedItems)
            {
                items.Add(ItemsChecked);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454058/no-itemchecked-event-in-a-checkedlistbox

Answer (score 1):

As is explained in the question that Mitja linked to, CheckedListBox isn't that good.

If you want a list of checked items, you can consider using a `ListView` instead, it has a [CheckBoxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes.aspx) property that you can set to `true` to get the same behaviour as you would get in a `CheckedListBox`, but with the added functionality of [ItemChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemchecked.aspx), since that event actually exist in the ListView control.

In your event listener, you can either get the checked item with the `e.Item` property (from ItemCheckedEventArgs), or get all checked items using the ListView's `CheckedIndices`, or `CheckedItems` properties.

Answer (score 0):

That occur because that event is raised when an item is about to have its checked state changed. The value is not updated until after the event occurs