# Add a TextBox when an item in a CheckedListBox is checked

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a programmatically created checkedListBox that has several options. What I want to be able to do is, when a user 'checks' an item in the checkedListBox, programmatically create a TextBox based on what was checked 'live' (without having to click another button or anything to create the TextBox).
([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RemY6.png))
The text box should also disappear if the option is unchecked.

So far here is what I have:

```
        private void rangetypecheckedlistbox_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
        {

            List<string> checkedrangetypes = new List<string>();
            foreach (object item in ((CheckedListBox)panel_corebonusbonuses.Controls["comboBox_corebonusbonuses_range_type_input"]).CheckedItems)
            {
                checkedrangetypes.Add(item.ToString());
            }
            foreach (string item in checkedrangetypes)
            {

                Label newdynamicvallabel = new Label();
                newdynamicvallabel.Size = new Size(201, 20);
                newdynamicvallabel.Name = "dynamic_label" + item;
                newdynamicvallabel.Location = new Point(100, 130);
                newdynamicvallabel.Text = item.ToUpper() + " VALUE";

                //Create range_type textbox.
                TextBox newdynamicvaltext = new TextBox();
                newdynamicvaltext.Size = new Size(272, 28);
                newdynamicvaltext.Name = "dynamic_textbox_" + item + "_input";
                newdynamicvaltext.Location = new Point(381, 127);
                newdynamicvaltext.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

                panel_corebonusbonuses.Controls.Add(newdynamicvallabel);
                panel_corebonusbonuses.Controls.Add(newdynamicvaltext);

                checkedrangetypes.Remove(item);
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't seem to create the textbox when I select a new item.
I am relatively new to c# and winforms and this is my first app in the language, so any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454058/no-itemchecked-event-in-a-checkedlistbox/4454594#4454594

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may know every click is considered as an Event in WebForms right?
You can use the *OnClick* Event when a checkbox is clicked and every Event contains ID of the the element clicked. Through ID, you can access other properties of the Element.

Example: (I don't have an active setup to test this... Your Code should look like something below)

```
    private System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox checkedListBox1;

    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
      Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public Form1(){

        //Initialize
        this.checkedListBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox();

        // Sets up the initial objects in the CheckedListBox.
        string[] myFruit = {"Range", "Threat","Blast"};

        // Changes the selection mode from double-click to single click.
        checkedListBox1.CheckOnClick = true;

       //Adding Event Listener
       this.checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += new System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventHandler(this.checkedListBox1_ItemCheck);


    }

    private void checkedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
    {                     
        List<string> checkedItems = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
    checkedItems.Add(item.ToString());

        if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
            checkedItems.Add(checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString());
        else
            checkedItems.Remove(checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString());

        foreach (string item in checkedItems)
        {
            var mPanel = new Panel(); //Cretae a Panel to add Textbox and Label
    
            //Create Label
            var newLabel = new Label();
            newLabel.Text = item;
    
            //Create text Box
            var newTextbox = new TextBox();
            newTextbox.ID = item + "_text_box";
    
            // add the label and textbox to the panel, then add the panel to the form
            mPanel.Controls.Add(newLabel);
            mPanel.Controls.Add(newTextbox);
            form1.Controls.Add(mPanel);
        }
    }
```